# File.Copy: копирование файла по сети - файл копируется не всегда

Tags: c#, windows, файлы

Добрый день!
Проблема следующая:
Необходимо скопировать в только что созданную папку файл с передачей по сети.
Сначала создаю папку и проверяю ее на существование и права доступа - с правами все в порядке - есть чтение и запись.

```
public void CheckAndCreate(string path)
    {
        if (!(Directory.Exists(path)))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
        }
        else
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
        }

        try
        {
            Directory.GetAccessControl(path);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
    }
```

Далее копирую файл:

```
CheckAndCreate(@"\\172.16.0.7\Dogovor\" + id_dogovor);
if (Path == "")
{
     Path = @"\\172.16.0.7\Dogovor\" + id_dogovor + @"\" + id_dogovor + ".docx";
}

while (!File.Exists(Path))
{
     File.Copy(directoryPath, Path, true);
}
```

В результате получаем: Файл почему-то копируется не всегда. Проверял на все исключения все в порядке. Хотя жестко задано, что Пока нет файла - копировать. Пробовал разными способами:

```
try
{
    FileInfo fn1 = new FileInfo(Path);
    while (true)
    {
        FileInfo fn = new FileInfo(directoryPath);
        fn.CopyTo(Path, true);
        if (fn1.Exists) break;
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
      if (IsCritical(ex))
      {  
          MessageBox.Show("Не удалось скопировать файл по причине: " + ex.Message);
      }
}
```

Еще пробовал после создания папки - создавать текстовый файл для проверки

```
 System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"\\172.16.0.7\Dogovor\" + new_dogovor + @"\TestFile.txt", "текст");

 System.IO.File.AppendAllText(@"\\172.16.0.7\Dogovor\" + new_dogovor + @"\TestFile.txt", "текст");
 StreamWriter file = new StreamWriter(@"\\172.16.0.7\Dogovor\" + new_dogovor + @"\TestFile.txt");                                                   file.Write("4444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444");
file.Flush();
file.Close();
```

Но все равно все безуспешно- файлы упорно не все записываются. Срабатывает через раз. Причем, если записывать файл через несколько минут после создания папки, то копируется все успешно, у меня все было во всяком случае в порядке. Пользуется данной программой уже около 50 людей. и периодически возникает эта проблема. Уже долго пытаюсь решить - нечего не выходит. Прошу помощи!

Comment: Если мне не изменяет память, во 2-м варианте получится бесконечный цикл, поскольку вы не обновляете информацию о файле `fn1`. Могу посоветовать копировать файл через `file2.Write(file1.Open().ReadToEnd())`. Тогда наверняка запишется.

Comment: а что это у вас за конструкция такая?  

    if (!(Directory.Exists(path)))
    {
       Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
    }
    else
    {
       Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
    }

Comment: Ну это да кривая немного)

Comment: file2.Write(file1.Open().ReadToEnd()). Не понял немного, а как file1, file2 определить, какой тип?

Comment: `while (!File.Exists(Path)) File.Copy`

Ну вы садист прям. Если файл невозможно скопировать по каким-то причинам, ваш код будет долбиться до бесконечности.

Comment: я так сделал, чтобы уж точно он туда записался, но ситуация в том, что он цикл проходит, а файла нет

Answer (score 1):

[[@romkaisanin](/users/19647/romkaisanin)](/users/19647/romkaisanin), чудес не бывает.

Если

```
 while (!File.Exists(Path)) File.Copy...
```

проходит (и Вы **абсолютно уверены**, что попадаете на этот `while`), а потом оказывается, что файла нет,

*то Вы ищете ошибку не там!*

Где-то после этого места кто-то иногда(!) удаляет файл (или Вы все таки не всегда попадаете на этот `while`).

Answer (score 1):

VladD прав в том, что делать такой while-цикл - слишком жестко, потому что он потенциально бесконечный. Но по факту бесконечно крутиться он не будет, т.к. любая исключительная ситуация приведет к выходу из него. А если такая не возникнет, файл все-таки скопируется, и будет штатное завершение. Я бы предложил сделать следующее:

1. Перенести try-catch конструкцию внутрь тела цикла.
2. После копирования добавить Sleep хотя бы на 1 секунду, чтобы дать
   файлу физически скопироваться и не дергать систему новыми запросами
   на копирование.
3. Ограничить число попыток чем-нибудь разумным, например 5 или 10 раз.
4. А вот за такой код, который мне показался по меньшей мере странным,
       Вас следует отругать:

   ```
   if (!(Directory.Exists(path)))
   {
       Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
   }
   else
   {
       Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
   }
   ```

Как-то мой руководитель радиокружка спросил: "Рома, какой сок будешь: персиково-яблочный, персиково-яблочный или персиково-яблочный?" К тому же зачем создавать директорию, когда она уже существует?